# pandas pivot table two lambda aggfuncs

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to pass multiple `aggfuncs` to `pd.pivot_table`:

if I have `new_df`:

```
                 ATI     ATIMR
0 Basin Creek    2.0  0.039893
  Calvert Creek  0.0  0.006824
  Lick Creek     0.0  0.017371
  Mule Creek     0.0  0.041154
  Rocker Peak    2.0  0.027903
  Saddle Mtn.    0.0  0.052603
  Shower Falls   1.0  0.035456
1 Basin Creek    3.0  0.039893
  Calvert Creek  1.0  0.006824
  Lick Creek     1.0  0.017371
```

This works:

```
   pct_75 = lambda y: np.percentile(y, 75)
   func_list = [np.median, np.mean ,pct_75]

   new_df = pd.pivot_table(new_df values='ATIMR',index='ATI',aggfunc=func_list)
```

But when I try and pass a second `lambda` function like:

```
pct_25 = lambda x: np.percentile(x, 25)

func_list = [pct_25, np.median, np.mean ,pct_75]
new_df = pd.pivot_table(new_df, values='ATIMR',index='ATI',aggfunc=func_list)
```

I get the following error:

```
InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assign the `name` to `lambda` function , if you do not do this , when apply two `lambda` functions , it will return the duplicated name error

```
pct_75 = lambda y: np.percentile(y, 75)
pct_75 .__name__ = 'pct_75 '

pct_25 = lambda y: np.percentile(y, 25)
pct_25 .__name__ = 'pct_25'
```

Comment: Better still, follow [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations) and make an actual function: `def pct_75(x): return np.percentile(x, 75)`.